# What types of bonuses can be applied with the fortify epic spell seed to boost intelligence?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, bonus-type

The DMG lists all the bonus types, some are common improvements to abilities, like enhancement or inherent. But what other types of bonuses could be applied to intelligence?

I could see the following being applied: alchemical, circumstance, competence, enhancement, inherent, insight, luck, morale, profane, sacred.

Surely a dodge bonus to intelligence is dumb, but perhaps I’ve missed a few other ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of different types of bonuses you can have. The core rules [list the different modifier types found in core](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#modifierTypes), but nothing says those are the **only** types there are—and non-core books invent new modifier types all the time, without making a big deal about it. It’s rare for them to even bother “explaining” that type of bonus, instead just letting them be self-explanatory.

Moreover, the whole alleged point of the epic rules is that they can go on forever. For there to be some final “limit” on the *fortify* seed would be entirely counter to that premise. *Fortify* indicates a price for using non-enhancement types, and that’s it—they effectively allow you to get an arbitrarily-large bonus as long as you pay for it.

So yeah, when you make your epic spell using the *fortify* seed, feel free to name any modifier type you like (and your DM agrees to), even if you just made it up. There is no rule saying you shouldn’t be able to, it’s entirely in keeping with the spirit of epic that you should be able to, and there’s simply no compelling reason to limit things.

Note, however, that this is a largely hypothetical concern—the epic rules are fundamentally broken, and you will not be able to maintain a coherent game based on those rules all the way out to the point that you have exhausted all the types you have in your question. The only way epic games can work is if you basically invent your own semi-freeform system that, at best, draws some inspiration from the epic rules. The epic rules themselves don’t work.

Comment: Agree on epic, but it’s not as though you can’t get an off-RNG high value for intelligence without much effort pre-Epic anyway.

Comment: @fectin Oh sure, it’s not a question of balance or even staying on-RNG, but it’s more like... you’re never going to exhaust even just the core bonus type list, so it’s all kinda moot.

Comment: “So its all kinda moot” may be the best general summary of the epic rules.